# Can I change base class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have 3 classes:

```py
class A:
    def __call__(self):
        print("a")
        
class B(A):
    def __call__(self):
        super().__call__()
        print('b')
        
class C(B):
    def __call__(self):
        super().__call__()
        print('c')

>> c = C()
>> c()
a
b
c
```

But I want to create class D with next output

```py
a2
b
c
```

easy way to implement in

```
class A2:
    def __call__(self):
        print("a2")
        
class B2(A2):
    def __call__(self):
        super().__call__()
        print('b')
        
class C2(B2):
    def __call__(self):
        super().__call__()
        print('c')
```

But the code for classes B and C hasn't changed, and I wouldn't like to rewrite it; I'd prefer to reuse it. To do that, I only need to replace the base class of class B. Please advise on the most correct, concise, and elegant solution

I want something like that:

```py
class A2:
    def __call__(self):
        print("a2")

B2 = B.change_base_to(A2)
C2 = C.change_base_to(B2)

>> c2 = C2()
>> c2()

a2
b
c
```

Comment: It really looks like composition would be a better approach than inheritance here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working with existing code that I didn't write. I just need to add some functionality, and the methods in classes B and C are quite extensive and complex, so I'm not very keen on rewriting all of it :)

Comment: If you're not comfortable rewriting the code, why are you comfortable with hacking it up in such a strange and unanticipated way?

Comment: I'm just looking for the best solution. If it turns out that rewriting the code is the best option, then so be it; I will go with that

Comment: It really, really is the best option. You don't necessarily have to rewrite everything -- it may be sufficient to wrap the existing functionality -- but subclassing properly to follow the Liskov Substitution Principle is hard enough without tying your code in knots by having the superclass itself be a varying concrete implementation of some unspecified superclass concept.

Comment: Python supports multiple inheritance. You can write your B and C as independent classes and then inherit from *B and A*, or from *B and A2*.